# Center the elements of a navbar on bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the elements of a navbar to be on the center, I have the following html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" style="bottom:50px; background:none; border:0px; box-shadow:none;">
            <div class="navbar-inner" style="float: none;">  
                <div class="container-fluid" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >   
                      <li><img class="social-media" src="images/facebook.png"></li>
                      <li><img class="social-media" src="images/twitter.png"></li>
                      <li><img class="social-media" src="images/linkedin.png"></li>
                    </ul>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here is my css:

```
.social-media {
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.social-media:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

[image]

I tried to  use `text-align:center;` on navbar inside the html but it didnt work. Any idea how can I solve this?

I've tried to change the bootstrap.css to

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
     float: none;
     text-align: center;
  }
```

and now I have this:
[image]

after editing bootstrap.css to :

```
 .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    display:inline-block !important;
    float:none !important;
  }
```

I finally got:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to set the `float:none;` on UL and `text-align:center;` on parent of UL

try the below css on UL and

**remember I am considering bootstrap 2.3.2 version NOT v3.X (if any not sure) if u are using other version let me know.. **

```
.navbar-nav {
    display:inline-block !important;
    float:none !important;
}

.container-fluid {
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

check the below [bootstrap sample](http://www.bootply.com/124034)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-fluid {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

By setting the left and right margins to auto, you are telling it to make both margins the same, which will center it. Do not remove the `text-align: center`.

Comment: it didnt help actually

Comment: Answer edited. Tested it and it works with the sample you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `.navbar-nav li` as `inline-block`, add `text-align:center` to `.navbar-nav`, this will position your icon in the center of navabar.

```
.navbar-nav{
    text-align:center;
}

.navbar-nav li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I changed the bootstrap.css adding your suggestion but nothing really happens. Thank you anyway.